# height and max-height of block elements - element doesn't showing up

Tags: html, css

1. Why when I set div element height with percentage the element doesn't showing up?
2. Why max-height never showing up? (No matter if it's percentage or vh or px) ?

For example:

```
<body> <div></div> </body>

div {width:50%; max-height: 100px; background-color: blue;}. Another Example: div {width: 50%; height:20%; background-color:blue;}
```

Never showing up :( Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if an element has a `max-height` attribute, you still need to tell it to consume it, because the default is `auto`. So if you want it to consume all height up to a maximum height you placed, use:

```
height: 100%;
max-height: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be because the element outside the `div` has a height of `0`.

In your example `body` has a height of `0` so any percentage of `0` is still `0`.

If you give your `body` (or outside element) a height it will be seen.

```css
.outerDiv {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.innerDiv {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    I'm inside
  </div>
  I'm outside
</div>
```